# make layout gone

Tags: android, visibility

when i use sliding drawer, i want a layout to gone so that sliding drawer will not be blocked.

However, i tried many ways such as

```
view = (View)findViewById(R.id.layout_latestcontent);
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_latestcontent);
    linear.setVisibility(2);
```

Both also cannot.

```
public void onDrawerClosed() {
    //view = (View)findViewById(R.id.layout_latestcontent);
    //view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void onDrawerOpened() {
    //view = (View)findViewById(R.id.layout_latestcontent);
    //view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Even implements both function also cannot

How to make the entire layout gone?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply value 2 (or any of [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility)) only in `android:visibility` view's property. If you wants to change View visibility from code you should use constants View.VISIBLE, View.INVISIBLE or View.GONE (constant values 0, 4, 8). `linear.setVisibility(View.GONE)` instead of `linear.setVisibility(2)` .

Comment: public void onDrawerOpened() and  onDrawerClosed() seem like cannot go in. When i open drawer, it does not disappear